# PHP autoloading failing due to file not being found

Tags: php, autoload

I am hosting on a GoDaddy shared hosting account.  My absolute hosting path is:

/home/content/a/d/m/admwta/html/eqflow/

I have a directory structure like this:

```
eqflow
->api
   ->classes
     ->security
     ->utils
   ->v1
```

I have defined one class per file hosted in either the security or util directory.  All files are all lower case and for the class names I followed the PEAR convention of _ to / so a file called getpasswordhash.php in the security directory directory has the name api_classes_security_getpasswordhash.

I have this autoload function:

```
function replaceunderscores ($classname) {
$path = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classname);
$fullpath = "/home/content/a/d/m/admwta/html/eqflow/".$path.".php";

echo $fullpath . " \n";
if (file_exists($fullpath))  {

    require_once ($fullpath);
}
else {
    echo "could not find file \n";
}
}
spl_autoload_register('replaceunderscores');
```

when I call login.php, it always fails with this message

/home/content/a/d/m/admwta/html/eqflow/api/classes/security/getpasswordhash.php 
could not find file 

**Fatal error**:  Class 'api_classes_security_getpasswordhash' not found in **/home/content/a/d/m/admwta/html/eqflow/api/v1/login.php** on line **27**

it is not passing the file_exists test in the autoload script, I don't know why?  You can see in the echo statement I put to echo full path I am giving the full path of the file?

Comment: Shouldn't `if (file_exists($fullpathpath))` be `if (file_exists($fullpath))`? Where is `$fullpathpath` coming from or populated from, or am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: yea, sorry, that was a typo on my part.  the statement is in fact if(file_exists($fullpath)).  You can see the construction of fullpath in the autoload function.  I prepend my hosting root to the value given by the str_replace function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by changing the way I constructed the $fullpath in the autoload function.  Rather than hard code the path, I used the `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` variable.  So for me the path becomes:

```
$fullpath =  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/eqflow/".$path.".php";
```

That works perfectly.  I am unsure what the difference is between hardcoding the document root and using the server variable but using the server variable worked.